# How to close VTKRenderWindow automatically

Tags: c++, opengl, vtk

I am using some simple code to render a mesh in a loop. In practice on each iteration I will change the viewpoint and save an image of the rendering. I have reduced this to a small compilable example below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader> fileReader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader>::New();

fileReader->SetFileName("benchvise_mesh.ply");
fileReader->Update();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata_ = fileReader->GetOutput();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> render_win = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor_view = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> cam = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    mapper->SetInput(polydata_);
    mapper->Update();


    cam->SetViewAngle(58);
    cam->SetClippingRange(0.00001, 10000);
    //Invert view Up
    cam->SetViewUp(0, -1, 0);
    cam->SetPosition(0, 0, -500);
    cam->SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 1);
    cam->Modified();

    actor_view->SetMapper(mapper);
    actor_view->Modified();

    renderer->SetActiveCamera(cam);
    renderer->AddActor(actor_view);
    renderer->SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    renderer->Modified();


    render_win->AddRenderer(renderer);
    render_win->SetSize(640, 480);
    //white
    render_win->Modified();


    render_win->Start();
    render_win->Render();
    render_win->Finalize();

}
```

}

The problem is, when I run this many vtkWindow icons appear on my taskbar and eventually bring the pc to a halt. It appears as though on each loop the rendering window stays alive. However, when I click on an icon the window doesn't actually appear.

Is there something I am missing that will clean up the render windows on each iteration.

BTW, I am running under Ubntu with vtk 5.8

Answer (score 0):

You do several things 'wrong' there. Remove everything wrong the loop, most importantly `render_win->Start()`, initialize at begin and just call `render_win->Render()` at each loop after the appreciated modifications to viewing has been made ( calls to mappers or cameras `SetPosition` and similars affect your view without reconnection, reconnection being call to `Add????()` -methods). `Modified()` calls should be implicit and not required manually.